# Show td table with class 2 / 2 col

Tags: jquery, css

**Html :**

```
    <span></span>
<table id="myList">
    <tr>
      <td class="td_0">test 1</td><td class="td_1">test 2</td><td class="td_2">test 3</td><td class="td_3">test 4</td><td class="td_4">test 5</td><td class="td_5">test 6</td><td class="td_6">test 7</td><td class="td_7">test 8</td><td class="td_8">test 9</td><td class="td_9">test 10</td><td class="td_10">test 11</td><td class="td_11">test 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="td_0">test 1</td><td class="td_1">test 2</td><td class="td_2">test 3</td><td class="td_3">test 4</td><td class="td_4">test 5</td><td class="td_5">test 6</td><td class="td_6">test 7</td><td class="td_7">test 8</td><td class="td_8">test 9</td><td class="td_9">test 10</td><td class="td_10">test 11</td><td class="td_11">test 12</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p></p>
<div id="loadMore">next 2 col</div>
<div id="showLess">prev 2 col</div>
```

**jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var colCount = 0;
    $('tr:nth-child(1) td').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('colspan')) {
            colCount += +$(this).attr('colspan');
        } else {
            colCount++;
        }
    });

    x=2;
    y=0;
    $('.td_0').show();
    $('.td_1').show();

    $('#loadMore').click(function () {

        x= (x+2 <= colCount) ? x+2 : colCount;
        $(".td_"+x).show();
        y= (y-2 <= colCount) ? y+2 : colCount;
        $(".td_"+y).addClass("masquer"); 

        $("span").text("y = " + y + " et x = " + x + " et colonne = " + colCount);
   });

    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        y= (y-2 <= colCount) ? y-2 : colCount;
         $(".td_"+y).removeClass("masquer");
        x= (x+2 <= colCount) ? x+2 : colCount;
         $(".td_"+y).hide();
       $("p").text("y = " + y + " et x = " + x);

    });

});
```

**css :**

```
.td_0 , .td_1 , .td_2 ,.td_3 ,.td_4 ,.td_5 ,.td_6 ,.td_7 ,.td_8 ,.td_9 , .td_10,.td_11 { display:none;
}
 .masquer { display:none !important;
}
 .back { display:table-row !important;
}
```

I want show and hide td like this :

test1 test 2

click on next :
test 3 test 4

click on next :
test 5 test 6

click on prev :
test 3 test 4
...

I have made a example run here :
[jsfiddle exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/6FzSb/3355/)

Thank you !

Comment: "it work a litle but not realy" your question isn't complete. describe what happend, what you want to happen. create a runnable example

Comment: thank you atmd, how make a runnable exemple please ?

Comment: I'm confused by what x and y are supposed to represent (axes? rows?) and why one starts at 0 and the other at 2.

Comment: Something more like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6FzSb/3356/ (still buggy, but maybe provides enough clues)

Comment: Just great !!!! Great great ! Thank you Max !

Answer (score 0):

i,

is it possible to creat a var to choose how many col show ?

for exemple :

```
$nb_col = 3;
```

how integrate this please ?

in this exemple :

[runnable exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/6FzSb/3360/)

thank you